# Python REST mysql db.commit() error

Tags: python, mysql, bottle

I am having the same error in python no matter where I put the db.commit() statement.

Here is my code:

```
from bottle import route, run
import json
import collections
import MySQLdb as db

@route('/register/<COD>/<NOMBRE>/<APELLIDO>/<DIRECCION>/<TEL>/<COD_FAC>', method='PUT')
def registrar(COD,NOMBRE,APELLIDO,DIRECCION,TEL,COD_FAC):
    c=db.connect('10.100.70.136','koala','toor','lab2',use_unicode=True)
    cur=c.cursor()
    sql1='SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE codigo="'+COD+'";'
    cur.execute(sql1)
    alumnos=cur.fetchall();
    i=0
    for alumno in alumnos:
        i+=1
        print(i)

    if i==0:

        operationResult=1
        operationMessage=""
        cur2=c.cursor()
        sql2='INSERT INTO alumnos (codigo,nombre,apellido,direccion,telefono,codigoFacultad) VALUES ("'+COD+'","'+NOMBRE+'","'+APELLIDO+'","'+DIRECCION+'","'+TEL+'","'+COD_FAC+'");'
        cur2.execute(sql2)




    else:
        operationResult=2
        operationMessage="El alumno con codigo "+COD+" ya se encuentra registrado" 

    db.commit()
    db.close()
    results = []
    d=collections.OrderedDict()
    d['operationResult'] = operationResult
    d['operationMessage'] = operationMessage
    results.append(d)
    j = json.dumps(results)

    return j

run(host='localhost',port=8080,debug=True)
```

The error that I get is this:

AttributeError("'module' object has no attribute 'commit'",)

And the description that I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg/bottle.py&quot;, line 862, in _handle
return route.call(**args)
File &quot;/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle-0.12.7-py2.7.egg/bottle.py&quot;, line 1729, in wrapper
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
File &quot;tarea.preg4.py&quot;, line 33, in registrar
db.commit()
AttributeError: &#039;module&#039; object has no attribute &#039;commit&#039;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call commit on the connection object - which is `c` in your case.  (so make it `c.commit()` instead of `db.commit()`)

You can find the python dbapi connection methods [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-methods).

Comment: that was the answer :) I'm sorry if this was an obvious question, but I'm not so used to code in phyton :)

Comment: Don't fret.  Every program you write brings you one step closer to mastery.  ...and this is one error you likely won't face again.